# changing name url address in github blog address

Tags: url, github

I've just created a my own blog on github.com, but the url to this site is http://wojtass.github.io/wojtass/ how can I change it to http://wojtass.github.io/?

Comment: have you try rename your project wojtass.github.com??

Comment: yes I solved this problem by changed name project, that how You say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your github pages repo exactly in this format: `username.github.io`. Rename your `wojtass` repo to `wojtass.github.io`.

Check out the steps for creating github pages [here](http://pages.github.com/).

Comment: Yes, thats solved the problem, thanks but I am to short a member and I can't vote up for your solving problem :(